# Laravel different routes for different roles

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel app with different roles admin, buyer and seller. In the routes file, I have routes with a prefix of admin and users and when the prefix is user, I then also check the role. A buyers has different permissions than a seller.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'user'], 'roles' => ['buyer']], function() {
        //
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'user', 'owner:bids'], 'roles' => ['seller']], function() {
        //
    });

});
```

This is giving me some strange side effects. For instance I cannot have two same routes for buyer (user 1) and seller (user 2). I would want to have

```
http://localhost:8000/user/1/dashboard
```

but instead I need to do

```
http://localhost:8000/user/1/dashboard/buyer
http://localhost:8000/user/2/dashboard/seller
```

So I'm beginning to think I just need to discriminate between admin and users (and not by buyers and sellers as I'm doing above), and check the roles in the controller files, not in the route.

What is the better way of working with admin and user for which users can have multiple roles?

Answer (score 0):

How is it that buyer and seller go to the same route and have the same id?
http://localhost:8000/user/1/dashboard

It is just one user that can do different actions then.

---

I would just add a field to users gate like is_admin and use some gates to check it. Same for your other similar question

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#via-the-gate-facade

Comment: If I don't use the roles middleware in the routes, then both would be user/dashboard. If I use the roles (buyer and seller as shown above in the route file), then I cannot take for both the route user/dashboard. Hence I have to call them /user/dashboard/buyer and /user/dashboard/seller.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Are you calling roles passing an {id} on the route?. You could use just one route and check everything on the controller

Comment: You mean to not use a middleware for that and check instead everything on the controller. I know it's a possibility, but I don't really understand why not using middleware to check the role. The advantage for middleware is that I every check is in the routes file. It works great, except for this small issue. But I have heard more people say that using middleware is in general not a good option. It's just that I'm not convinced as I don't really understand why not.

Comment: Gate is easier to manage permissions when it's more than just admin or user. I use route when only to check if admin. If you want to use in this case admin middle and buyer, and seller, it would be possible, but more complicated than with gates I think. So probably your code in the middle for those is not correct yet.

Comment: You can also group in a middleware the gate's checkings